# Fetched Firebase Data is not showing into Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have created a listview where I want to put all the fetched data according to the result of the previous activity values. Like, I have a Spinner and an Edittext then a search button.

The result will be according to the spinner value and edit text value both. But it is not coming. Please help.
Below my Test class with its layout file (here the spinner and edit text present)
and The SearchResults activity, and Useradapter (model class)

**Test.java**

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner sp;
EditText e1;
Button logout, searchuser;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);

    logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    searchuser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutt1);
    sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.selectblood) ;
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchpin);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    final String[] bloodgroups = new String[]{"A+","A-", "B+", "B-","O+", "O-", "AB+", "AB-"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, bloodgroups);
    sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String bloods = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String pin1 = e1.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, Searchresults.class);
            intent.putExtra("bloods", bloods);
            intent.putExtra("pin1", pin1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this);
            alert.setMessage("Are you Sure?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignupPage.class);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialogg = alert.create();
            dialogg.show();


        }
    });
}
}
```

**Layout file (Fragmenthome.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/button">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bloodimage"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32999998" />

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/selectblood"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/searchpin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Enter Pincode"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchbutt1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpressed"
    android:text="Search"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpressed"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchbutt1" />
```

**Searchresults Activity**

```
public class Searchresults extends AppCompatActivity {
String pinfin;
String bloodfin;
ArrayList<String> donorList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
public static ArrayList<UserAdapter> donorInfo;
DatabaseReference myRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_searchresults);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    bloodfin = extras.getString("bloods");
    pinfin = extras.getString("pin1");

    donorList = new ArrayList<>();
    donorInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_donor);
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, 
    donorList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    myRef.child(bloodfin).child(pinfin).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            UserAdapter donor = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAdapter.class);
            donorInfo.add(donor);
            assert donor != null;
            String donorInfo = donor.namefin  + "   \n" + donor.gender + "   \n" + donor.phonefin + "   \n" + donor.addfin + "   \n" + donor.bloodfin ;
            donorList.add(donorInfo);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Searchresults.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
}
```

}

**UserAdapter Class**

```
public class UserAdapter {

public String email, namefin, addfin, statefin, phonefin, pinfin, bloodfin, gender;

public UserAdapter(String email, String namefin, String addfin, String statefin, String pinfin, String phonefin, String bloodfin, String gender) {
    this.email = email;
    this.namefin = namefin;
    this.addfin = addfin;
    this.statefin = statefin;
    this.phonefin = phonefin;
    this.pinfin = pinfin;
    this.bloodfin = bloodfin;
    this.gender = gender;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getNamefin() {
    return namefin;
}

public String getAddfin() {
    return addfin;
}

public String getStatefin() {
    return statefin;
}

public String getPhonefin() {
    return phonefin;
}

public String getPinfin() {
    return pinfin;
}

public String getBloodfin() {
    return bloodfin;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setNamefin(String namefin) {
    this.namefin = namefin;
}

public void setAddfin(String addfin) {
    this.addfin = addfin;
}

public void setStatefin(String statefin) {
    this.statefin = statefin;
}

public void setPhonefin(String phonefin) {
    this.phonefin = phonefin;
}

public void setPinfin(String pinfin) {
    this.pinfin = pinfin;
}

public void setBloodfin(String bloodfin) {
    this.bloodfin = bloodfin;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
myRef.child(bloodfin).child(pinfin).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        UserAdapter donor = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserAdapter.class);
        donorInfo.add(donor);
        assert donor != null;
        String donorInfo = donor.namefin  + "   \n" + donor.gender + "   \n" + donor.phonefin + "   \n" + donor.addfin + "   \n" + donor.bloodfin ;
        donorList.add(donorInfo);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(donorList, getContext());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```